# Mongorestore not importing data

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I am trying to restore a mongo db dump. Running mongorestore on a PC works fine. But when i run it on a linux server (64bit MongoDB), no error is thrown, but the data is not imported. 
Given below is the message on the terminal :

```
#mongorestore --drop dump
connected to: 127.0.0.1
Sun Nov  4 11:56:13 dump/m101/hw1.bson
Sun Nov  4 11:56:13     going into namespace [m101.hw1]
Sun Nov  4 11:56:13      dropping
1 objects found
Sun Nov  4 11:56:13     Creating index: { key: { _id: 1 }, ns: "m101.hw1", name: "_id_" }
Sun Nov  4 11:56:13 dump/m101/funnynumbers.bson
Sun Nov  4 11:56:13     going into namespace [m101.funnynumbers]
Sun Nov  4 11:56:13      dropping
100 objects found
Sun Nov  4 11:56:13     Creating index: { key: { _id: 1 }, ns: "m101.funnynumbers", name: "_id_" }
```

Edit:

This was a non-issue. The problem was not with the insertion, but with my querying. I was trying to do db.m101.funnynumbers.count(). The correct way of doing it is db.funnynumbers.count().

Comment: What's your mongodb version with both PC and linux?

Comment: Are you certain the data didn't get imported?  According to your output it appears that documents were restored to the `m101` database (1 document into the `hw1` collection and 100 into the `funnynumbers` collection).

Comment: @Chien-WeiHuang Its 2.2.0 in both my pc and linux. PC is 32 bit version and linux is 64 bit.

Comment: @Stennie I went into the console and checked. db.m101.funnynumbers.count() gives 0. (tried find() operation too in this collection)

Comment: @Siddharth: you need to first do: `use m101` to change to the database, then `db.funnynumbers.count()` to count documents in the collection.  Alternatively you could do `db.getSiblingDB('m101').funnynumbers.count()`.

Comment: @Stennie Thanks a tonne. It was this silly mistake from my end. :) Thanks a lot again.

Comment: No worries ... at least you found the answer ;-)

Comment: I see some discussions in the course talking about the same problem, too. Maybe You can take a look at those discussions first :)